# React set draggable antd modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, antd

I'm trying to add a antd modal with drag&drop features.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
import { Modal } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    disabled: false
  };

  render = () => {
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <Modal visible>
          <Draggable>
          <div>
            <h4 style={{ height: 20, userSelect: "none" }}>
              {"Drag Me"}
            </h4>
            <textarea disabled={!disabled} className="uk-textarea" />

            <br />
            </div>
        </Draggable>
          </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Here's my sanbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/small-currying-j3emq, but it seems that react-draggable in **ant modal** element doesn't work, probably if I can set the element **"ant-modal-content"** as draggable element this works.

Does anyone know if it is possible to put the draggable element via props in react-draggable?

I am also available to change the package for drag & drop, I just need to be able to drag a antd modal

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just place your `<Draggable>` inside your `<Modal>` and not the opposite

```
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Modal visible>
          <Draggable>
            <div>
              <h4 style={{ height: 20, userSelect: "none" }}>{"Drag Me"}</h4>
              <textarea disabled={!disabled} className="uk-textarea" />

              <br />
            </div>
          </Draggable>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: no, in this case it gives me the possibility to drag & drop only the content, not the modal

Comment: oh, i get it now. Then check this out https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/3012